# Vaccine based on cell reaction?

Tags: biology

Suppose a virus entering a cell and adding DNA code.

Now if these new genes would activate other cell genes, then one could build a vaccine based on these newly activated cell genes, so that the vaccine would not contain the virus genes but those.

Could this be used to make new type of vaccine ?

Answer (score 10):

## We are doing that right now

...or at least very close to it.

[image: T-Cells]

*[xkcd 938: T-cells](https://xkcd.com/938/)*

As mind-boggling as it sounds, yes, we are essentially using HIV's special ability to [mess] with T-cells — i.e. the "commanding officers" of the immune system — to issue orders to immune system that "Hey, if you find anything with this DNA, **KILL IT**".

Presently, cancer treatments using this method are in Phase 2 trials, where they are taking a sample of the patient's cancer, putting that into HIV — or HIV-like viruses — and then injecting into the patient. These viruses then "patch" the patient's T-cells to make the body start to attack the cancer.

---

Also, it may have come to your attention that right now there is this massive vaccination campaign ongoing to do something about [a certain pandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic)...

The vaccines used for that do *not* contain weak versions of the SARS-CoV-2 virus, but instead trigger the body to make a protein that is normally found on the surface of the vaccine. The body then forms an immune response to these proteins. So then — when the SARS-CoV-2 virus *does* show up — the body is prepared and can attack it quickly and effectively.

[There is an xkcd for that as well](https://xkcd.com/2425/), though too large to post here (thank you @Trioxidane).

---

So, to summarize: what you are asking, it is not only feasible, we are more or less doing it *today*. The old style [Jenner vaccinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Jenner) — where you use a weak form of an actual virus to teach the immune system what to look for — is outdated tech by now.

Comment: Of course XKCD made a comic about the mRNA vaccines as well. Give the body plans for the mRNA. It'll happily start making the mRNA. Body suddenly sees foreign material (despite creating it itself) and start to defend itself. Save this in T and B cells for later (real) attacks. https://m.xkcd.com/2425/

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't work.

As you state, the virus would activate the cell's genes. Whatever the cell's gene is expressing will be recognized as self by the organism where the cell is living and won't normally trigger an immune reaction.

Only non-self is able to trigger an immune reaction, so it has to be expressed by the newly added genes.

Comment: Not entirely true. Although the cell is forced to do the virus's will, they can still detect and react to a virus. As far as I can tell, this happens in most cases. The cell secretes interferons (?) to signal the immune system and nearby cells. It often requests destruction of the infected cell and for the nearby cells to try to shield themselves.

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge of the matter is literally 10 years out of date, so bear with me for a while.

It wouldn't be a vaccine per se, it would be more like serum therapy or adding clavulanate to penicilin compounds

### Interfering RNA

When I was in university (10 years ago), the theme of my end of course dissertation was about using siRNA for inhibiting production of a specific protein that made cancer cells more resistant to chemotherapy. So in a very crude way, we were trying to "jam the signal" that made the cells produce that protein.

So this technique can be used to treat diseases caused by the body producing what it SHOULDN'T make but it is recognized as being its own, so it doesn't trigger an immunologic response - as of this day, there are a few treatments under clinical trial for diseases that fit this description like porphyria and amyloidosis.

This is also tested in certain viral diseases like hepatitis.

Related wikipedia articles for the summary:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_interfering_RNA

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_silencing

Answer (score 1):

**It would both work and very much not**

How I'm reading the question is that a virus infects a cell. The virus DNA is added. Thanks to this, multiple parts of the 'normal' DNA starts expressing itself, making the whole cell a virus factory. You're asking if we can make a vaccine not against the viral DNA, but against the 'normal' DNA that starts expressing when it's a virus factory.

As we can make markers and such to spot and hunt down such DNA chains, we certainly could. The problem is that it's already in our DNA. You're asking the immune system to attack harmless cells in many occasions.

So you could do it, but likely you're also setting the body up to attack itself in many normal circumstances. In bad cases, you could destroy a whole group of cells. Imagine a tuberculosis vaccine that now starts eradicating most of the lung cells.

I'm not an expert. There are near certainly smart people who can (and are) still use this to an advantage. Still I would advocate not to train the body to attack cells that exhibit normal DNA expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Virophages might be the answer. Virophages are a kind of virus that can infect other larger viruses (Girus). They can move in with a virus which takes over a cell. Then they interfere with viruses in all kinds of manners.

- Take over the hijacking the virus does and compete with the virus for reproduction in the cell.
- Or hijack the created viruses genetic information so that they will create virophages the next time around the virus infects a cell.

Now imagine a virophage that hides inside human DNA, remaining dormant until a virus infects it. Once the cell is infected by a virus, the genes activate and release the virophage, the virophages taking over the viroplasm and starts creating new virophages instead of virusses.

Now you have a self-replicating and spreading, virus destroying cure. It would work like a vaccine, in that you would need to be injected with it before getting sick, but it doesn't seem unlikely that it would help too when already sick.

For some more information/inspiration, these might be helpful:
[Kurzgesag: Informative video](https://youtu.be/1-NxodiGPCU?t=420)
[The video's sources](https://sites.google.com/view/sources-girus/)

Comment: This is why Kurzgesag is problematic.  People watch the videos and draw the wrong conclusions.  There is _one_ virus sufficiently large to be a target of virophages that has potentially been identified as a human pathogen.  Coding for virophages in human DNA is not going to help against pretty much any dominant human pathogens.